# AngularJs Table with showing top 5 and bottom 5 rows?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to Angularjs and i want to show top 5 and bottom 5 rows in between click all functionality which shows all the records. I tried different things but not able to get success.

```
            <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="dataTables_wrapper" id="comparison-table">
            <table class="datatable">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th width="5%">A</th>
                  <th width="10%">B</th>
                  <th width="25%" class="text-left">C</th>
                  <th width="15%">D</th>
                  <th width="15%">E</th>
                  <th width="15%">F</th>
                  <th width="15%">G</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>##</td>
                  <td class="text-left">AA</td>
                  <td>12</td>
                  <td>12</td>
                  <td>2</td>
                  <td>4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>2</td>
                  <td>##</td>
                  <td class="text-left">BB</td>
                  <td>12</td>
                  <td>11.7</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>3</td>
                  <td>##</td>
                  <td class="text-left">CC</td>
                  <td>12</td>
                  <td>11.7</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>4</td>
                  <td>##</td>
                  <td class="text-left">DD</td>
                  <td>11.7</td>
                  <td>10.7</td>
                  <td>9</td>
                  <td>3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>5</td>
                  <td>##</td>
                  <td class="text-left">EE</td>
                  <td>12</td>
                  <td>10.4</td>
                  <td>3</td>
                  <td>9</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="text-center br" colspan="7"> <a href="#">Click to view all</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>32</td>
                  <td>##</td>
                  <td class="text-left">FF</td>
                  <td>12</td>
                  <td>12</td>
                  <td>2</td>
                  <td>4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>33</td>
                  <td>##</td>
                  <td class="text-left">GG</td>
                  <td>12</td>
                  <td>11.7</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>34</td>
                  <td>##</td>
                  <td class="text-left">HH</td>
                  <td>12</td>
                  <td>11.7</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>35</td>
                  <td>##</td>
                  <td class="text-left">II</td>
                  <td>11.7</td>
                  <td>10.7</td>
                  <td>9</td>
                  <td>3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>36</td>
                  <td>##</td>
                  <td class="text-left">JJ</td>
                  <td>12</td>
                  <td>10.4</td>
                  <td>3</td>
                  <td>9</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
```

please find the fiddle just for demo purpose - 
        http://jsfiddle.net/samirshah1187/Br28J/

Comment: Your first sentence is quite confusing. Do rephrase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I have understood your question correctly, you want the first and last five rows to always be visible, with the option to toggle the rows inbetween? If so, try this:

**Controller:**

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    // Create Test Array
    $scope.myArray  = Array.apply(null, {length: 20}).map(Number.call, Number)
    $scope.hideRows = true

    $scope.toggleHiddenRows = function() {
      $scope.hideRows = !$scope.hideRows
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="value in myArray" ng-hide="hideRows && $index > 4 && $index < (myArray.length - 5)">
      <td>Row: {{value}}</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
  <button ng-click="toggleHiddenRows()">Toggle Hidden Rows</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks mate. it was in my mind to create directive for this but was not sure. you solved my query.

Comment: Is there any way i can not have directive for this?